# How to run rake task as a worker process on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, rake-task, worker-process

Let assume that I have scaled Heroku application to 1 worker process, but how to specify that the rake task with particular name should run as a worker process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a Procfile in your project, and put the rake task within it like so

```
worker: bundle exec rake my:cool:rake_task
```

More info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

UPDATE (April 2014):

If you want to schedule your rake task like a cron job you could use the [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/marketplace/scheduler)

Details are here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler